# macOS Mojave. PHP 7 installed but Apache uses PHP 5.6.6. How to fix?

Tags: php, macos, apache, php-7, macos-mojave

PHP 7 is installed because if I type in terminal the following command, I get this output:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:19:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

But if I run phpinfo() in my php web pages, I get PHP 5.6.6 is used and not PHP 7.

I uncommented the LoadModule for php7 in the Apache conf file, but nothing changes.
I also tried to changes other configuration files without success.
I also tried using Homebrew but it seems it completely screwed up the environment. I uninstalled it.

Is there a way to "reset" or "clean" the environment and start from "skratch" with php7 for web development on my Mac?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

PHP command line interface (CLI) can run a different version than Apache2. You need to disable php5 module and enable php 7 with regards to Apache. The names might differ a little bit depending on your version, but on Ubuntu it's basically:

```
a2dismod php5
a2enmod php7.0
service apache2 restart
```

It sounds like you're using a Mac. In which case, you can achieve the same thing by editing /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and explicitly adding the passenger module:

Instead of PHP 5

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

You'll want PHP 7

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Remember, you'll have to restart Apache before the changes take place.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Also, it appears that on Mac Homebrew can cause multiple installs of Apache2. You'll want to make sure you're editing and removing the correct one. Here's some more info on that:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269310/macos-apache-installs-on-different-directory-with-homebrew-how-to-start-stop/270848#270848

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348004/remove-homebrew-apache2-fails